# What is $C^1_c(\mathbb R)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

It seems both weird and ridiculous that I can't find online the meaning of $C^1_c(\mathbb R)$.

I would be grateful if you could explain how one would go in finding such a symbol without asking a question here..

I guess it is the space of functions that are continuosly differentiable on $\mathbb R$, I don't understand what the little $c$ means though..

Comment: The $c$ means "compact support".

Comment: It is also denoted $\mathcal C_0^1(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: @CaptainLama Thanks. Then my professor is partly to blame because apparently he used up until now the notation $C^1_0$.

Comment: @Surb Exactly, that was the source of my confusion. Hate that they change the notation without even telling

Comment: Weird, for me $\mathcal{C}^1_0$ means that it has limit $0$ at infinity. Well, notations...

Comment: $C_0^1$ means that each $\{x\mid |f(x)| \geq \epsilon\}$ is compact for every $\epsilon > 0$ to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The little $_c$ here is usually used to indicate that the set only contains the continuously differentiable functions that are *compactly supported*. A function $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is compactly supported if $f$ is identically zero outside some finite interval.